# Monitoring files with twisted

Tags: python, twisted

Is it possible to write a Twisted application to monitor addtion of new files/folders to a specific folder? If yes, could someone point me to some code/link trying to do it, or give an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, you can have [inotify with nice Twisted integration](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.inotify.html).

Hopefully someday there will be something similar for Windows and perhaps *BSD (based on kqueue), but for now Twisted only ships with support for this on Linux.

Comment: Ok Thanks I need it on windows did you know if there is option to do that on windows with twisted ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not yet.  There is a Windows API that might someday be integrated with IOCP reactor, though - it's the same one Jakob mentioned in his answer, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need twisted, but of course you can integrate it. Basically you need yo use inotify.

Take a look at https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

Answer (score 0):

Windows or linux?

Windows:
http://tgolden.sc.sabren.com/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Linux:
http://www.lambda-computing.com/projects/dnotify/

Comment: Neither of your links mentions Twisted and the second one doesn't even mention Python. How does that apply to the original question?

Comment: Because using twisted which is a network application to do a OS specific task is weird, anyway. Twisted is a networking framework so why not use these links then push the information over a twisted connection